# Show Last element in QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qmodelindex

It sounds trivial, but I could not find the function to show the last added element in a QListView.

It works with a model

```
// Create model
model = new QStringListModel(this);

// Make data
QStringList List;
// Populate our model
model->setStringList(List);
// Glue model and view together
listView->setModel(model);
```

Elements are added with

```
void WidgetMessageList::addString(const QString & message)
{
    if(model->insertRow(model->rowCount())) {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(model->rowCount() - 1, 0);
        model->setData(index, message);        
    }
}
```

In this function the shown element should also be the last.

Comment: QAbstractItemView::scrollTo?

Comment: Works! `listView->scrollTo(index);`

Comment: then let's put it as an answer )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAbstractItemView::scrollTo

> Scrolls the view if necessary to ensure that the item at index is
>   visible. The view will try to position the item according to the given
>   hint.

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class attibute to hold the last index
2. Connect [QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) to a slot in your application
3. In the slot update the index accordingly

Comment: I will also prepare an example. Stay tuned.