# How to show latest entry on a QListView always on top

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qlistview

As is possible to see from the print screen below I have the following **problem:** as I add the entry via `QPushButton` I don't want the last entry to be the last of the `QListView` but instead I want it to be at the top of the `QListView`. How do I make the QListView always showing from the latest entry to the last entry?

[image: view_wrong]

**The desired behavior** is with the latest entry on top:

[image: correct]

Below the code:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mView = new QGraphicsView();
    mScene = new QGraphicsScene();
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(mScene);

    QFont font;
    font.setPixelSize(10);
    font.setBold(false);
    font.setFamily("Calibri");

    mText = new QGraphicsTextItem;
    mText->setPos(150,70);
    mScene->addText(tr("Boat outside alarm area"))->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::black);

    model = new QStringListModel();
    ui->listView->setModel(model);
    ui->listView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);

    connect(ui->listView, SIGNAL(loggingUpdated()), this, SLOT(updateListView(const QString &)));
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::updateListView(const QString & message)
{
    if(model->insertRow(model->rowCount())) {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(model->rowCount() - 1, 0);
        model->setData(index, message);
        ui->listView->scrollTo(index);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
    model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
    QModelIndex index = model->index(model->rowCount()-1);
    model->setData(index, str);
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QStringListModel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void updateListView();
    void updateListView(const QString & message);

signals:
    void loggingUpdated();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsView *mView;
    QGraphicsScene *mScene;
    QGraphicsTextItem *mText;
    QStringListModel *model;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I wonder if there is some missing signals I didn't catch or if at this point I should use a `Q_PROPERTY` but I am not sure if that is actually the right route. I am running out of ideas on how to solve this issue.

**What I have done so far:**

I researched the problem and came across [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312714/show-last-element-in-qlistview) that helped me set the proper index. However it did not help to completely solve the problem.

I also consulted the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo) however my problem is not related to how scolling should be, but how to determine the latest entry and put it as first item of the `QListView`.

I didn't stop there and dug more and arrived to [this command](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) but I am not sure it applies coorectly to the problem I am solving.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::updateListView(const QString & message)
{
    if(model->insertRow(0) {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(0, 0);
        model->setData(index, message);
        ui->listView->scrollTo(0);
    }
}
```

should do the job , no ?  currently you insert your row in the last position, simply insert it on the first one...

Comment: Thanks again for the advise you gave me :). If you also think my question was clear please give me thumbs up :) have a great day!